# Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

What am I misunderstanding about how to use the `.subscribe` function in combination with the `.do` function?

Here is my observable sequence:

```
  lookupSubscriber = (text$: Observable<string>) =>

  text$.debounceTime(300)
     .distinctUntilChanged()
     .do(() => this.searching = true)
     .switchMap(term => {
        var data = this._callApi(this.lookupSubscriberAPI, term)
           .do(() => {
              this.searchFailed = false;
              this.searching = false;
           })
           .catch(() => {
              this.searchFailed = true;
              this.searching = false;
              return Observable.of([]);
           })
        return data;
     })
     .do(() => this.searching = false);
```

If my _callApi function is as follows, it works:

```
_callApi(url: string, term: string) {
  if (term === '') {
     return of.call([]);
  }

  return map.call(this.dataService.get(url + term), response => {
     var data = this._transformSubscriberInfo(response);
     return data;
  })
```

}

However, when I try to rewrite it with a `subscribe` function like this:

```
   _callApi = (url: string, term: string) => {

     return this.dataService.get(url + term)
        .subscribe(
           response => { this._transformSubscriberInfo(response) }, 
           error => error.text(), 
           () => {
              if (Logging.isEnabled.light) {
                 console.log('%c API Call Complete', Logging.normal.orange);
              }
        ))
}
```

... then the data call succeeds, but I receive error: `Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.`

Basically I am trying to catch errors and run an "always" function after the api call, as shown in the second version of `_callApi`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version of `_callApi` seems to return an `Observable` while the second one returns a `Subscription` object. And `Subscription` does not expose `do`, exactly as the error message states.

What you may want to try is to use a version of `do` that accepts `error` and `complete` callbacks in addition to the `next` callback:

```
return this.dataService.get(url + term)
    .map(response => this._transformSubscriberInfo(response))
    .do(
        response => { /* log response */ }, 
        error => { /* log error */ }, 
        () => { /* log completion */ }
    );
```

It worth mentioning that `do` is not capable of transforming the source stream, the observable it returns contains the same values as the observable it is called on. That's why we need the line `.map(response => this._transformSubscriberInfo(response))`.

Also `complete` callback should not be confused for an "always" function: it gets called only when the source observable completes and it does not get called when the observable produces an error or gets unsubscribed.